# The match() method in Angular? How to do it?

Tags: angularjs

I've searched the Angular docs and I can't find any way to do this in angular.

Seems bizarre to me. It's a simple JS method on an object. Why can't I use it in angular?

This is fine in plain JS:

```
time.match(/\d+:\d+:\d+/);
```

But in angular it doesn't work and neither does:

```
 $scope.time.match(/\d+:\d+:\d+/);
```

I get an error saying match() isn't a function.

Comment: Check if `$scope.time` is a string, quick fix will be `($scope.time || '').match(...)`

Comment: Seems, that `$scope.time` is not a string nor another object that has a `match` method. You should provide more code.

Comment: `($scope.time.toString() || '').match(...)`

Comment: $scope.time is a date. Why does it work in JS but not in angular?

Comment: Also - none of those suggestions work. I get errors.